# Firebase User signOut in swift list button

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, swiftui, swiftui-list

I'm trying to set up a button in my list view to allow the user to sign out of their account from the device. I followed as video on setting up sign in and out and I'm confident with those but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Here's my code:

```
struct SettingsAccountView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var session: SessionStore

    func getUser() {
        session.listen()
    }

    var body: some View {
        List {
            Section {
                Button(action: {
                    print("Change USER email")
                            }) {
                    SettingsCell(title: "Change Email", imgName: "envelope.fill", clr: Color("Waterfall"))
                }

                Button(action: {
                    print("Change USER password")
                                    }) {
                    SettingsCell(title: "Change Password", imgName: "eye.slash.fill", clr: Color("Waterfall"))
                }

                Button(action: {
                    print("Change USER Photo")
                            }) {
                    SettingsCell(title: "Change Profile Photo", imgName: "camera.rotate", clr: Color("Waterfall"))
                }
            }

            Section {
                Button(action: session.signOut) {
                    print("SignOut")
                }) {
                    SettingsCell(title: "Sign Out", imgName: "person.crop.circle.badge.xmark", clr: .red)
                }
                Button(action: {
                    print("Delete MY Account")
                            }) {
                    SettingsCell(title: "Delete My Account", imgName: "trash.circle", clr: .red)
                }
            }

        }.listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
            .environment(\.horizontalSizeClass, .regular)
            .navigationBarTitle("Account", displayMode: .inline)
    }
}

struct SettingsAccountView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SettingsAccountView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be a problem where you incorrectly specified the `action` parameter for this button:

```
Button(action: session.signOut) {
    print("SignOut")
}) {
    SettingsCell(title: "Sign Out", imgName: "person.crop.circle.badge.xmark", clr: .red)
}
```

It looks like you added an extra closure as an action block. Your action parameter can be either a function (like `session.signOut`) or a closure (like `{ print("SignOut") }`). It can't be both of them.

Try this code instead:

```
Button(action: {
    self.session.signOut
    print("SignOut")
}) {
    SettingsCell(title: "Sign Out", imgName: "person.crop.circle.badge.xmark", clr: .red)
}
```